# Como obter um valor dentro de um array

Tags: php, array

```
array(3) {
     ["recebidos"]=>
      array(16) {
        [0]=>
        array(25) {
          ["contratante_id"]=>
          int(1028)
          ["datacadastro"]=>
          string(20) "2019-08-01T12:30:44Z"
          ["observacoes"]=>
          NULL
          ["situacaoantiga"]=>
          string(5) "Ativo"
          ["turma_id"]=>
          int(1672)
          ["mataluno_id"]=>
          int(3157)
          ["horarioentrada"]=>
          NULL
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sérgio, você está com um array multidimensional.

Para acessar as informações você pode trabalhar com `foreach()`, por exemplo.

```
    foreach($recebidos as $p => $kp){

            extract($recebidos[$p]);

            echo $contratante_id . '<br>';
            echo $datacadastro . '<br>';
            echo $observacoes . '<br>';


}
```

Há outras maneira para se resolver o que precisa. A de cima resolve seu problema, conforme array que você postou.

Espero ter ajudado